# What is wrong with this code? (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's probably a stupid mistake but my brain is just not working today.

I have a button and two `<h1>` Elements. They animate when you push the button and I wanted it to fade away when you hover over the text.

Also the button hides itself when you push it.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        $('#text1').animate({right: '700px'}, 'slow');
        $('#text2').animate({right: '900px'}, 'slow');
        $(this).toggle();
    });

    $('#text1', '#text2').mouseover(function(){
        $('#text1', '#text2').fadeTo('slow', 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: Increase the quality of your question(s) by providing a descriptive title and a proper explanation of the issue. A future reader will have a hard tim trying to identify whether they have the same problem as you, because you don't actually describe the problem. All you are saying is "my code doesn't". Guess what? Most people that ask a question here have code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just the selector.

```
$('#text1, #text2').mouseover(function(){
    $('#text1, #text2').fadeTo('slow', 0);
});
```

`$('#text1', '#text2')` actually uses the `$( selector [, context ] )` form - explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) -, meaning that the `#text1` must be inside `#text2`. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I just split it up into two statements and it worked!

Comment: @masongeloso No need for 2 statements, just use the code provided by Carlouuus.